# If showPopup only goes to API 11, how do I link a Menu to a View with ABS?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

> Note: PopupMenu is available with API level 11 and higher.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu

With that in mind, how can I link a menu to a View on screen with ABS and the compatibility library? I have a menu imageview on one of my layouts that I would like to provide a universal menu option. Basically by having an imageview that pops up the menu, the same system is in use regardless of device or android version. But if popup only exists on Gingerbread and later, is there another way to link an ImageView (+ click listener) to open up my menu?

Comment: you can use `PopupWindow` and `showAsDropDown()` instead. here is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10120510/1326010) to a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up solving this:

```
    ImageView menuImg = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.menuImageView);
    menuImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            activity.openOptionsMenu(); //This is the key method!
        }
    });
```

---

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;    
}
```

---

```
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.demographics:

            return true;
        case R.id.settings:
            Log.v("v", "settings clicked");
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
     }
}
```